# How to deal with unknown PHP cURL result

Tags: php, curl

In case of not sure about the incoming data format and content of curl setup, what is the way to show or deal with the result in any format.

as example

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: That's why servers send back headers like Content-Type

Comment: Use [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: @Anthiny, thanks, but in a very ambiguous case, that we may not even sure about the correct options and parameters. the header maybe not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` will help you to return the response of curl in `$result`. Otherwise it will be always empty.

Using `$headers = curl_getinfo($ch);` you can get the response headers from the curl request and then check what is the `content-type`. Based on that you can decide what to do.

Here is the sample code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$headers = curl_getinfo($ch);

print "Content-Type: " . $headers['content_type'] . "\n";
print "response: $result\n";
```

Comment: thanks, but in a very ambiguous case, that we may not even sure about the correct options and parameters. the header maybe not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do with it specifically, the easiest way you can dump whatever response you get is this:

print_r($result);

This will just simply dump everything you received onto the page so you can understand what it is the server is returning.